# How to search for a pattern of words in shell script?

Tags: shell, awk, grep

I want to search for a pattern of words in a text file.
The pattern is like:

```
Summary: ........... Fault
```

The dots indicate anything can come in between.
How can this be done in shell script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the 'General Regular Expression Parser' utility, aka grep. Suppose the name of your file is `dump.txt`. Use the command:

`cat dump.txt | grep "Summary: .*Fault"`